# How to return a dictionary and multiple variables from a function in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, dictionary, return

I am trying to set up a function that records to 2 variables and a dictionary, the dictionar works but the two variables return the wrong things

```
mydict{}
fname = 0
lname = 0

def enterdetails(fname, lname):
    fname = input ("First Name: ");
    fnamedict = fname
    mydict['FirstName'] = fnamedict;

   lname = input ("Last Name: ");
   lnamedict = lname
   mydict['LastName'] = lnamedict;
   print(fname)
   print(lname)

   return mydict
   return (fname, lname)

fname, lname = enterdetails(fname, lname)
print(fname, lname)
print(mydict)
```

However the variables of fname and lname come out as FirstName and LastName respectively. How would I fix this?

Comment: You can't return multiple variables. A solution would be putting them all in one dict.

Comment: Your code does not make sense, you have 2 return statements, only the first one will execute. You can return a tuple of your dict and variables like so `return mydict, fname, lname`

Comment: You could look into using a [yield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) statement instead though.

Comment: @VincentBeltman -  you can absolutely return multiple variables - return them in a tuple - just as the OP is doing in the line `return (fname, lname)`- although the brackets aren't needed in this case.

Comment: @VincentBeltman: not true.

Comment: ``return`` returns an object so wtever you are wishing to return just use in an object like **tuple** or anything.

Comment: Ok thankyou, im new to python and i wasn't sure exactly how to do it properly.

Comment: your `enterdetails` doesn't need any arguments....

Comment: @PsychedelicPanda If your query was resolved, don't forget to accept an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `return` statements, but only the first is returned. Instead, return all three variables together as a tuple:

```
def enterdetails(fname, lname):
    ...
    return mydict, fname, lname

mydict, fname, lname = enterdetails(fname, lname)
print(fname, lname)
print(mydict)
```

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary works because you have it set as a `global variable`.
However, the function is actually returning the "dictionary" first, so your unpacking is all messed up.

Remove the `return mydict` or use `return mydict, (fname, lname)`, so you will end up with:

```
mydict, (fname, lname) = enterdetails(fname, lname)
```

But as I mentioned above, `mydict` is a global variable, so it is unnecessary to return the value.

Comment: I had to read this twice to understand it, but that is a very good point about global variables that the other answers didn't address.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `return` under a `return` like

```
return mydict
return (fname, lname) #this won't return any thing
```

One of the ways that you could do is:

```
  ....
  return [mydict, fname, lname]

data = enterdetails(fname, lname)
mydict = data[0]
fname = data[1]
lname = data[2]
```

Comment: you don't need to use a list to return multiple items - you can just use `return mydict, fname, lname` and then `mydict, fname, lname = enterdetails(fname,lname)`when you call it.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 yeah just mentioned one of the ways, edit it to make it better

Comment: Another answer has been posted using tuple - no point changing your answer to copy someone elses.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 didn't see the other answer so left mine as it was previously